# How to prove that E[X] < E[Y]?

Tags: probability, expected-value

Consider two random variables $X$ and $Y$ such that $P(X \le Y) = 1$ but $P(X = Y) < 1$, that is $P(X < Y) > 0$. Then, how do we prove that $E[X] < E[Y]$?

My attempt is as below:

Let $A = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: x = X(w) < Y(w) = y \}$,
then
$$
E[Y] 
= 
\int_{\mathbb{R}} x \, dF_{Y}(x)
= 
\int_{\mathbb{R}/A} x \, dF_{Y}(x)
+ 
\int_{A} x \, dF_{Y}(x)
$$
but not able to get it to the end.
And, I am not familiar with the measure theoretic approach.

Comment: You might find it easier to find some $\epsilon >0$ such that $p_\epsilon=P(X + \epsilon \le Y)>0$ in which case $E[Y]-E[X] =E[Y-X] \ge \epsilon p_\epsilon>0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}[Y - X] &= \operatorname{E}[Y - X \mid Y = X]\Pr[Y = X] + \operatorname{E}[Y - X \mid Y > X]\Pr[Y > X] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[Y - X \mid Y - X > 0]\Pr[Y > X] \\
\end{align}$$
and since $\Pr[Y > X] > 0$ and $\operatorname{E}[Y - X \mid Y - X > 0] > 0$, the result follows.